# Gatsby site's images aren't showing on mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, github-pages, gatsby

I'm building portfolio site with Gatsby+Wordpress combination. If I run this setup locally or at Github pages everything seems to look normal when using desktop/laptop. If I visit site which is published to Github pages and view with mobile device images aren't showing at all.

I found [this solution](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5264#issuecomment-405424852) and added it to my `gatsby-node.js` like this:

```
const _ = require(`lodash`)
const Promise = require(`bluebird`)
const path = require(`path`)
const slash = require(`slash`)


// This is the solution I found but it's not working in my case
// ----------
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  process.env.GATSBY_WEBPACK_PUBLICPATH = "/"
}
// ----------

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
...
```

I didn't found any other solutions and it seems that I can't solve it by myself.

[Link to site](https://imlastrebor.github.io/portfolio/)

[Link to repo](https://github.com/imlastrebor/portfolio)

Hopefully I provided enough information so you can catch the idea, if not ask and I tell more. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I visit your site with Chrome or Firefox no images at all are showing even on desktop.

Comment: Thanks for this. I figured if I stop running Wordpress locally images doesn't show anymore at all. I don't know why is that because all the image files should be found from portfolio repo.

I added link to the repo. You can find it from my question.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by changing the way I query images. At first I used for example this:

```
query {
    wordpressWpPortfolio {
     acf {
      portfolio_gallery {
       source_url
       }...
```

This produced wrong kind of URLs for images. Images pointed to my localhost instead of folder inside my repo.

I changed query method to this:

```
   query {
    wordpressWpPortfolio {
     acf {
      portfolio_gallery {
       localFile {
        childImageSharp {
         fluid(maxWidth: 500, quality: 100) {
          src
          srcSet
          aspectRatio
          sizes
          base64
         }...
```

This query for gatsby-image had to be done manually because gatsby-config.js doesn't support fragments like:

```
fixed(width: 300, height: 300) {
   ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[This line in your gatsby config](https://github.com/imlastrebor/portfolio/blob/7db185b87822da913878da9ec7cdd93b03d2e39b/gatsby-config.js#L53) looks to be the issue: `baseUrl: "localhost:8888/robertsalmi.fi",`

I suspect the wordpress plugin uses that to prefix all the images, as your live site is showing them all with that base url. You'll need to provide the correct base, so it can build the image links properly.

Comment: Yes I think it might be something with that. If I query images like this: ```allWordpressWpPortfolio {
      edges {
        node {
           portfolio_gallery {
              source_url}}}}``` images got URL which points to localhost. If I query images with ```childImageSharp``` then its points to URL /static/... That folder in my repo contains the images but now I have issue that I got this error to console```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()```

Comment: I found out that images that are queryed with ```childImageSharp``` just needs repo's name added to their URL. For example, image has now URL something like this : ```https://imlastrebor.github.io/static/0fd96c360c6fcbeb3aafa01a9fb57851/0aa4b/maidot_rivissa_FB.jpg``` and the URL should be like this ```https://imlastrebor.github.io/portfolio/static/0fd96c360c6fcbeb3aafa01a9fb57851/0aa4b/maidot_rivissa_FB.jpg```. How can I add my repo's name (/portfolio) to the URLs of the images? I have already added ```pathPrefix: `/portfolio`,``` to the ```gatsby-config.js```